# check return type of Function

Tags: java

I have this:

```
class Male extends Person{..}
class Women extends Person{..}

// returns true if the return type of the given function is of type Women
boolean isReturnTypeWomen(Function<Integer, Person> function){
    
    Class<?> type = function.getClass().getMethods()[0].getReturnType();

    return type.isInstance(Women.class) ? true : false;

}
```

However, it always return true because `type` is always `Object`.

How can I check the instance type of the second parameter (the return type) of the given `Function`)?

Comment: The return value of this function is _always_ `true`, because of its signature.  For an arbitrary function, you can rarely be sure and will have lots of false negatives, at a minimum, due to erasure.

Comment: it will not even compile if is not `String` in the second parameter. what is the actual question?

Comment: @Eugene my example was a little bad. I changed it. The question is: how to get the type of the second parameter (the return type) from the given Function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't not be - the parameter is a `Function<Integer, String>`.

`getMethods[0]` doesn't work. For example:

```
public class Example implements Function<Integer, String> {
    public void completelyUnrelatedMethod() {}
    public String apply(Integer i) { return null; }
}
```

This will return `void` here.

More generally there is no need for that runtime check - the generics take care of it:

```
Function<Integer, Integer> ohDearThisDoesNotReturnAString = a -> a;
isReturnTypeString(ohDearThisDoesNotReturnAString);
```

The above doesn't even compile.

To do a deep dive on your actual code, which utterly does not work:

Generics are erased, which mostly means that generics are usually a figment of the compiler's imagination. At runtime the information is simply gone. This isn't always true, but it usually is or can always be, so what you want (a runtime check) is **impossible** to guarantee.

In addition, you've messed up the check. `isInstance` does what `instanceof` does: It requires a type and **some object**. What you have is 2 instances of `Class<?>`; the right method for this is `isAssignableFrom`, not `isInstance`. As you have discovered, it doesn't work and cannot work - that's that erasure thing.

Answer (score 2):

Some `Function` subclasses will provide an `apply` method with covariant return type and a synthetic bridge to forward invocation across. However, `Function` instances will typically be lambdas or function references, so will not.

Consider, as a counterexample, the following method.

```
public static <T,R> Function<T,R> nothing(Function<T,R> fun) {
    return t -> fun.apply(t);
}
```

The `Function` returned by this method will always be of the same class, but `T` may change. Therefore the class cannot reference the type.

A benefit of this is that the function objects do not need to carry around the overhead of extra data to represent type arguments, which are of no use in type-safe code anyway.